# Symfony Deserialization of CSV data into Array of objects

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I have a php class with one property that uses DateTimeInterface. the other properties are string, int, etc.

php class

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
private ?\DateTimeInterface $eff_date = null;
```

In my Controller I process some CSV data to populate the class (header row followed by multiple data rows).  I setup the serializer like so.

```
   $encoders = [new CsvEncoder()];
    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer(), new DateTimeNormalizer()];
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
```

Two step process works mostly (single deserialize step does not work)

1. decode step
2. denormalize step

```
    $output = $serializer->decode($data,'csv');
    dump($output);
    
    $an_object_array = [];
    
    foreach($output as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
            $an_object = $serializer->denormalize($item, Rmk::class);
            $an_object_array[] = $an_object;
    }
    
    dd($an_object_array);
```

If I set the property as a string the serialization works fine.

if not I get the following error.

> Failed to denormalize attribute "EFF_DATE" value for class
> "App\Entity\Rmk": Expected argument of type "?DateTimeInterface",
> "string" given at property path "EFF_DATE".

Comment: Also tried :  

        $normalizers = array(
            new DateTimeNormalizer([
                DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => "d/m/Y",
            ]),
            new ObjectNormalizer(
                null,
                null,
                null,
                new ReflectionExtractor()
            ),
            new GetSetMethodNormalizer(),
            new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution.

1. changed the setter method in the entity to accept string as input and create a date time object from the string.
2. corrected normalizers

```
    $normalizers = array(
        new ObjectNormalizer(),
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    );
```

2. switched to single deserialize step also.

```
    $remarks = $serializer->deserialize($data, Rmk::class.'[]','csv');
```